# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ? NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a website about logging in with node js but I don't know how to solve this problem. If you don't mind. Could you please explain about these error for me?

my error

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

my code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var path = require('path');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'nodelogin'
});

var app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'))
})

app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;
    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FORM accounts where username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                response.redirect('/home')
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username or Password');
            }
            response.end();
        })
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }
})

app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        response.send('Welcome back, ' + request.session.username + '!');
    } else {
        response.send('Please login to view this page')
    }
    response.end();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your results variable seems undefined. Please check if sql query is not returning null.

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating that results is not defined. You can put
`console.log(results)` right before the results.length > 0 conditional to see what results is.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have any error checking mechanism, please update the code to handle any errors sent by the MySQL package

```js
connection.query('SELECT * FORM accounts where username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
   if (error) {
       // You need to check this error
       console.log(error);
       response.send('Some Error has occurred');
       return;
   }
   if (results.length > 0) {
       request.session.loggedin = true;
       request.session.username = username;
       response.redirect('/home')
    } else {
       response.send('Incorrect Username or Password');
    }
   response.end();
})
```